# PHP: Unset session JUST on update

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have a HTML form with information. If the submitted data is incorrect an error message will appear with a back button. A session with the submitted data is stored and filled in the form field when the user press the back button.

But I want the session to unset if the user update the site (like press F5). How can I do this?

I use this to show the stored data in the field when the user press the back button:

```
<b>Comment</b><br>
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="text">' . $_SESSION['text'] . '</textarea>
```

I can use `unset($_SESSION['text']);` at the top of the page but then the data will not show in the form. Any idea?

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem -- please tell us about X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `unset($_SESSION['text']);` at the bottom of the page.

First data will display then session will unset when user press F5.

```
// at the bottom of the page add below code

if(isset($_SESSION['text'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['text']);
}
```

Comment: unset($_SESSION['text']); worked! Just had to place it at the bottom of the if-statement. Surprisingly, it didn't worked when I placed the code at the end of the page. Thx mate! :D

Answer (score 1):

Unset session after echoing it.

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="text">' . $_SESSION['text'] . '</textarea>
<?php unset($_SESSION['text']); ?>
```